# Verbose rmiregistry - how can I trace rmiregistry state?

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

Is this possible to trace somehow state of my rmiregistry? It would be nice to have at least some logger-like info:

```
[timestamp1] Object1 bound at localhost/OBJECT1
[timestamp2] Object2 unbound at localhost/O2
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an appropriate `logLevel` system property as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html). There are several, for different layers of the RMI system.